# How to resolve an undefined Promise error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In my React app, I'm fetching the NASA API to get the Rovers photos.
To allow me to have a better code structure I built a Promise with timeout utility as follow

```
export async function PromiseWithTimeout(promises, timeout) {
  let promise = promises;
  if (promises instanceof Array) promise = Promise.allSettled(promises).then(console.log);
  return Promise.race([promise, throwTimeout(timeout)]);
}

export const throwTimeout = (msec, message = 'timeout') => reject(msec, message);

export const reject = (msec, retVal) => new Promise((_, r) => setTimeout(r, msec, retVal));
export const resolve = (msec, retVal) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, msec, retVal));
```

The result of this utility as an example from console.log is as follow:

```
0: {status: "fulfilled", value: {…}}
1: {status: "fulfilled", value: {…}}
2: {status: "fulfilled", value: {…}}
```

I have the result of the call of the function above which is used in a next way inside the component but The problem is in the `.then()` here I'm getting that `forEach()` is undefined and when I `console.log(rovers) === undefined` I have no clue what wrong. I'm getting my Promises resolved but I'm not getting in further in the system

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      await PromiseWithTimeout(
        [
          getRoverManifest('curiosity'),
          getRoverManifest('opportunity'),
          getRoverManifest('spirit'),
        ],
        3000
      ).then(
        (rovers) => {
          rovers.forEach(savePhotosManifest);
          if (rovers.some((rover) => rover.photo_manifest === undefined))
            this.setState({ error: true, isLoading: false });

          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            rovers,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching Rover Manifests: ', error);
          this.setState({ error: true, isLoading: false });
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error Mars Rover Page: ', error);
      this.setState({
        error: true,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `result` in the `then` block of `Promise.allSettled`

**Like this**

```js
promise = Promise.allSettled(promises).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  return res;
});
```